# what do the # numbers in *.i files represent

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor

I want know about the steps of execution of c program. I got this intermediate file which i can't understand 
what are these numbers in the screenshot represent and what exactly that line it do.

```
# 1 "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h" 1 3
# 9 "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h" 3
```

[take a look at ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujcXP.png)

Comment: Please post code as `formatted text`, not images. Also provide the commands you're using to generate this file

Comment: Please don't show images of text. [Edit] your question and copy-paste a party of the text you wonder about into the question, *as text*.

Comment: Those are line numbers to match up preprocessed C with the original source, I think.  With nested includes it can get fairly complex, but compilers can use this to print better warning messages (like where the original definition was of a conflicting prototype or something.)

Comment: what is .i file?

Comment: for gcc .i file `#` means comment

Comment: @P__J__: `.i` is the default name for `gcc -E` preprocessed output.  BTW, this is not actually assembly, it's preprocessed C.

Comment: @PeterCordes I know what gcc .i file is but OP did not mention it. So I aked the question

Comment: @rici:  were you planning to leave a comment about where the answer to this question is buried somewhere on a question about a different topic ([What is the difference between #include  and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593))?  I flipped through the answers and I don't see any talking about the `gcc -E` output metadata lines like `# 1 "filename" 1 3`.  I don't see how this is duplicate of that; please explain or re-target to an actual duplicate.

Comment: @peter: sorry, I don't know how that happened. There are dozens of appropriate dupes: when i get to a machine with a usable intergace I'll add some mire.

Comment: @rici: Ok, I'll leave it closed for now.  My answer here doesn't go much beyond my comment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`.i` files are where [`gcc -save-temps`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-save-temps) outputs *preprocessed C*.  **This is C, not assembly language**.  You'll find asm in the `.s` file.

---

**Those are line numbers to match up preprocessed C with the original source**.  I don't know exactly what the number at the start vs. the one or two numbers after the filename mean.  If you need to know the details, you might need to look at GCC internals, or maybe it's documented somewhere.

With nested includes it can get fairly complex, but compilers can use this to print better warning messages (like where the original definition was of a conflicting prototype or something).

GCC has the C preprocessor built-in to the compiler pass so I'm not sure it actually needs to (or can) read these "comment" metadata lines in the `.i`; in normal operation the main C->asm compiler pass knows file/line-number of everything it read without having to serialize it into this text format and back.

GCC does have options to read preprocessed-C as input, specifically [`-fpreprocessed`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fpreprocessed) which is on by default if you were to run `gcc -c foo.i`.

> Indicate to the preprocessor that the input file has already been preprocessed. This suppresses things like macro expansion, trigraph conversion, escaped newline splicing, and processing of most directives. The preprocessor still recognizes and removes comments, so that you can pass a file preprocessed with -C to the compiler without problems. In this mode the integrated preprocessor is little more than a tokenizer for the front ends.
>
> `-fpreprocessed` is implicit if the input file has one of the extensions `.i`, `.ii` or `.mi`. These are the extensions that GCC uses for preprocessed files created by `-save-temps`.

So this is what lets GCC still remove those lines starting with `#` that are like preprocessor directives.  (Like `#define` or `#include`).